# Given the set of length of triangle, find the Maximum Area Triangle

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is an array contains the possible length of a triangle. Find which three length can build a maximum triangle.

I can compute all the area of possible triangle(Heron's formula) to find the max one, but the running time is terrible. How can I design a algorithm which the running time is (n*n)?

Comment: and what makes you think O(n^2) running time won't be terrible?

Comment: @Geobits The area of triangle(6,6,6) is greater than triangle(6,6,7)

Comment: @Geobits I think you are right

Comment: But Area(6,6,6) is greater than Area(6,6,11). So it can't be the longest three lengths.

Comment: [Crossposted on cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18459/98).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can solve this problem in linear time, except that you will have to order your set of triangle length first, which is O(nlogn).

Here's how I would do it.

PSEUDO-CODE:

```
// V is the set of length of triangle.

Order(V)

// Heron Formula
define A(a,b,c) = SQRT(4a^2*b^2 - (a^2 + b^2 - c^2) ^2) / 4 

// I is the last position in V
I := V.length - 1

// T(I) is the area of Maximum Area Triangle
T(I) =
if V[I]^2 <= V[I-1]^2+V[I-2]ˆ2
     then return A(V[I-2],V[I-1],V[I])
else 
     return MAX( A(V[I-2],V[I-1],V[I]), T(I-1) )
```

Explanation:
Assuming that c>=b>=a, when c^2<=a^2+b^2, if you increase any of the variable (a, b or c), you will have a triangle that has a larger area. So, if you peak the three largest numbers and the equation c^2<=a^2+b^2 is true, that means you have found the largest area. But, if c^2<=a^2+b^2 is not true, that is c^2>a^2+b^2, than a triangle with a different setup might have a greater area. If we change b or a with a lower value, will we have lower area, so that is not an option. So, the only option we have is to choose a diferente value for c, which is T(I-1), which is also a recursion. The maximum value between A(V[I-2],V[I-1],V[I]) and T(I-1) will be your answer.